# Drupal 6 AHAH / AJAX Form Submission

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, submission, ahah

I'm building a custom module in Drupal 6 which display a block with a form and some other elements like text and images.  When it's submitted, using AHAH, some logic takes place in PHP and then the result is passed to JQuery which will update the elements in the block.  Mainly a few images and some text.

I can't wrap my head around using AHAH, but it seems like that's what I'm supposed to be using.  Currently I have my form with the submit button implementing '#ahah' and the path is set to a path defined in my menu hook.  The menu hook passes it to the callback function which performs the logic then I'm at a dead end.  How do I get the results to jQuery?

Any ideas?

Howie

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution using: http://drupal.org/project/examples.